# What is wrong with my Printf statement? (SYNTAX)

Tags: unix, printf

I am trying to use printf to align some columns up I am not very familiar with the syntax of the printf command so I will give an explanation of what I want it to do

```
printf("%-15s %-15s %25s\n", Fname, Lname, Num)
```

I want to create 3 columns one called "Fname" one called "Lname" and one called "Num"

I want the Fname column to be left aligned and 15 spaces long, same with the Lname column I don't care about alignment in the Num column, but I want it to be slightly longer at 25 characters

This is my error

> Syntax error near unexpected token `"%-15s %-15s %25s\n",'

Comment: What language are you using? `printf` is a function in almost all of them...

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the brackets to enclose the statement.
Also, i guess that you may need to be handling `Lname`, `Fname`,`Num` as variables too, so you would need to correct this also.

Correct syntax:

`printf "%-15s %-15s %25s\n"  $Fname, $Lname, $Num`